# Extruding faces

Tags: modeling

I followed direction in the [BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbbH0.jpg) book. In the Logo Design exercise on pages 38 & 39 the process of creating shapes and giving them faces is described.  I did that successfully.  Then it says to extrude the faced shapes.  When I tried that all that resulted was another set of filled shapes that are not connected at the sides.

Could someone please tell me how to do that so that the result is a 3D object instead of two 2D shapes?

Thanks for the quick replies.

I as I described previously I attempted to make faces on the shapes I created.  The book described using a Plane to modify vertices and extrude them to make a closed shape.  I did that proceeding along a background image.  When I got back to the beginning, the shape would not close by holding down the Shift Key and pressing "F".  I selected the last two vertices and then used the Merge command to close the shape.  Is that wrong?

When I then tried to mesh the complex shapes individually by hitting Ctrl-"F" that operation did not work, so I worked around the shapes picking 4 vertices and then hitting "F".

I thought I had good faced complex shapes.  Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Then I tried pressing A twice to select all, then W > bridge and that did not work, so I selected individual edge loops on related close faced shapes and then bridging those edge loops.  One set of shapes worked but the other two failed.

[image]

That looks like the shape was not closed.  Did I close the shape incorrectly?

If you were trying to prepare to teach Blender, what text resource would you choose?

As to changing the surface normals, I tried that and everything looked good but still extruding did not work properly.

Referencing the third answer:  Turn Textured solid OFF, and see if there are any faces. [ Press N to open up the side tab ] and the image provided, what I see in my menu is different.  Here below is a screen shot of Blender. You can see that I am tracing the Calhoun Community College Logo.

[image]

Comment: How did you extrude the faces?  It should be done by pressing [E], at a glance It looks more like you have hit [Shift]+[D] (duplicate).  Although you also have some zero-width faces which would not be from an extrusion or duplication.

Comment: With it as your screenshot looks now, try pressing A twice to select all, then W > bridge.

Comment: A general note, not specifically oriented to this problem: I looked up the PDF you are referring to and it is using Blender 2.5 which is *very* old, a *lot* has changed and improved since then.  I would recommend getting a more up to date resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways :

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in edit mode to Re-Calculate the normals.
2. Make sure you extruded the correct way (as in the following pictures).
3. Turn Textured solid OFF, and see if there are any faces. [ Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the side tab ]
4. It looks like you're in wireframe view. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to solid view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **Note:** Ctrl-N doesn't flip the normals it tries to guess which way the should go.

Answer (score 1):

When you press<kbd>F</kbd>, blender makes a face between all of the selected edges/vertices. *One face*.

In your example, you selected a whole lot of edges, and blender made one face spider-web between all of them. A proper n-gon (quadrilateral) has four edges, one face, and four vertices.

Try just selecting *four* vertices at one time. Then hit <kbd>F</kbd>.